# Accessing list via getter causes stack overflow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two classes `MenueController` and `SaveMenue`.

**SaveMenue**

In `SaveMenue` I have a private list variable of type `<Text>` called `textElements`, which has a getter.

```
private List<Text> textElements = new List<Text>();
public List<Text> TextElements {
    get {
        return TextElements;
    }
}
```

**MenueController**

In `MenueController` I created an object of the class `SaveMenue` and then tried this:

```
...
SaveMenue = new SaveMenue(savePanel);
...        
Debug.Log(SaveMenue.TextElements[SaveMenue.SelectedIndex].name.ToLower());
```

But I get `**StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.**`

---

**SaveMenue**

However, if I change `textElements` to public and remove the getter...

```
public List<Text> textElements = new List<Text>();
```

**MenueController**

...and try it like this:

```
Debug.Log(SaveMenue.textElements[SaveMenue.SelectedIndex].name.ToLower());
```

Then it works and there is no stack overflow exception.

Why is there a stack overflow if I use the getter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return TextElements` calls the getter for `TextElements`. Return the backing field instead.

```
private List<Text> textElements = new List<Text>();
public List<Text> TextElements {
    get {
        return textElements;
    }
}
```

You can prevent this kind of mistake from happening by prefixing your private fields with an underscore. Then you know at a glance: If your getter gets (or your setter sets) something without an underscore prefix, you need to fix it. Intellisense is case blind, but it won't ever mistake `_` for `T`.

```
private List<Text> _textElements = new List<Text>();
public List<Text> TextElements {
    get {
        return _textElements;
    }
}
```

Comment: whoops, my fault :/ ... thanks for the hint.